# Setting up different log4net logging levels based on transformations in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have installed `log4net`, and have the following setup:

```
<configuration>
  <log4net debug="true">
    <!-- two appenders -->
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="SlackAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

This is perfect, because locally I want to debug everything two my appenders.

Now, I want to log only errors in production.

I tried to edit my `Web.release.config` I am quite sure I didn't do it correctly:

```
 <log4net debug="true">
    <root>
      <level value="ERROR" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Because it doesn't have a key, so I cannot do this.

What is the best practice here?

Comment: Use the User XPath expression...something like `xdt:Locator="XPath(\\configuration\log4net\root\level)"`

Comment: @ste-fu Do you have an example? :-)

Comment: Sorry...not at my computer.